# Java client QueryBuilder for both date range and terms or order by timestamp asc

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm looking for a sample Java client QueryBuilder that can search by date range + terms + order by timestamnp ASC

My attempt

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("time").gte("now-10d/d").lt("now/d"))
    .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("_type", "war-log"))
    .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("event", "ADD"));
```

Comment: This what are you looking for: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/25230032/3710490](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25230032/3710490)

Comment: Can you explain in more details why your query doesn't work so far? maybe if you can show some sample document that should match it would help.